# How to check statistics for messages sent to topics via FCM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Statistics for messages sent via FCM can be checked in Google Play Developer console using the message ID or the registration token. But when I try to run FCM diagnostics using the message id returned when message is sent to a topic, an invalid message id error is shown. There is also no mention of this in FCM documentation. Does some one know how to check stats for fcm messages sent to topics ?

Comment: It also seems that the linked FCM Messages statistics in the Developer Console, only show the number of API _requests_ made that target a topic. That is, it does not show the number of messages sent to devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Play Developer Console Diagnostics feature does not currently support tracing of messages sent via the topics API.

In general, there is currently no way to trace the status of the messages using topics.

Comment: Is there any way to get diagnostics from the API, using the message_id returned when sending to a topic?

Comment: @nickdnk AFAIK, there is no available API that gets diagnostic details similar to what you see in your Play Developer Console. But what kind of *diagnostics* were you hoping to get? Do expound. :)

Comment: Such as how many were opened, how many we delivered and so on. When posting to a topic you only get the message_id in return. Is there anything we can use that ID for?

Comment: @nickdnk You can only use it to check if the message (for the topic) was sent towards the  FCM server. The statistics on how many were sent, opened, and any others isn't seem to be available. However, if you need a more in-depth debugging with regards to an FCM message, you can contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/) directly along with the details (specially the related message_id(s)).

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll store the message ID along with the message in my app server for debug purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can configure FCM export (via Firebase console) to BigQuery. The export happens on daily basis and the exported data has schema detailed here https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=android#what-data-exported
You can then run your query (BigQuery console) using topic and event type (e.g. MESSAGE_ACCEPTED, MESSAGE_DELIVERED...)