# FCM Push Server topic messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm considering to apply [FCM topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging) in our Push Server using http.

In our legacy system, we used [GCM multicast messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) that receives maximum 1,000 registration_ids and returns the result per device. So we could measure how many devices have received push message. And we could remove invalid registration_id from database according to the result.

My question is that is there any way to get the same information when we move to our legacy to FCM? Because the topic api seems not to return the data.

If exists, how can I get the information?

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to receive the details (e.g. `message_id`s) when using topics (see possibly related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39389049/4625829) -- it mentions about not being able to get statistics when sending to topics).

If you're gonna proceed with using FCM, you'd still have to use `registration_ids` in your requests, each with only 1000 tokens.

In summary, when sending messages to topics, the response details are the same for both GCM and FCM; both return a single `message_id`.