# How to know the successful delivery of GCM topic messages

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a gcm topic which have 2 million users .Can some one please suggest  a way to know the number of successful deliveries for a particular message ,other than the way client acknowledges the same?
I need a server side option to know the number of succesful deliveries for gcm topic messages.

Currently when I send the following post request

```js
https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

I am able to get only the following response:

> {
>     "message_id": "10"
>   }

Comment: Try adding [`delivery_receipt_requested`:true](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#receipts), to enable a device that confirms it received a particular message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check statistics for messages sent to topics via FCM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386727/how-to-check-statistics-for-messages-sent-to-topics-via-fcm)

Comment: @Mr.Rebot is this applicable for gcm topics